# how to read byte[] from stream Reader in GetrResponseStream()

Tags: asp.net, wcf, http

I have one WCF services returning Byte[] data.how can i read this data on client side

```
using GetrResponseStream();

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
     if (responseStream != null)
     {
         var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
         string dataString = reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
}
```

using this code im getting

```
dataString ={"[255,34,56,778,3,54,6,8,9,90,0,87,6,.....]"}
```

but i want `byte[]` returned by that WCF services i.e i want

```
byte[] dataString =[255,34,56,778,3,54,6,8,9,90,0,87,6,.....];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
return memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: getting error "'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a definition for 'CopyTo' and no extension method 'CopyTo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.StreamReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader` is mainly used to reading text data, you can use the `Stream` class `GetByte` to read your response in a `byte[]`. See the code below:

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     using (Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
     {
          /// you'll have your response in this variable
          var buffer = new byte[responseStream.Length];
          long bytesRemaining = responseStream.Length;
          int bytesRead = 0;

          while (bytesRemaining > 0)
          {
              int readCount = stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, 1024);

              bytesRead += readCount;
              bytesRemaining -= readCount;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: @ abdul using your code i'm getting exception on very fisrt line "This stream does not support seek operations."